# Apache Camel FTP 550 Error while deleting the files in linux

Tags: java, linux, ftp, apache-camel, jbossfuse

As per the [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6056) there was issue in FTP file moving or deleting(which in-turn moves the file to .folder after deleting) on linux system.

The fix for issue is available from 2.10.5. But in Jboss Fuse Server 6.0, the default features are 2.10.0. Kindly suggest us the best way to sort this issue.

Comment: To get help with JBoss Fuse product, and to get a hot-fix / workaround etc, should use the Red Hat customer portal: https://access.redhat.com/home

Comment: Yes we can do that. But the problem is now we are working in POC. Kindly Help.

Comment: CAMEL-6056 is included in JBoss Fuse 6.0. Maybe you have a different/related problem. You get 30 days free support when you download JBoss Fuse 6.0, you can use that to get help.

Comment: Thanks claus, the issue is with commons-net-3.2 jar. I upgraded to 3.3 and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the answer, the issue is with commons-net-3.2 jar. I upgrade to 3.3 version and now its working.

```
--Upgrade the version of commons
uninstall commons-net 3.2 version
install mvn:commons-net/commons-net/3.3

--Steps in Configuring Fuse Server

1. To view dependencies of a project bundle
    command -> dev:show-tree bundle-id

2. To uninstall a bundle :
    uninstall bundle-id
    uninstall commons-net 3.2 version

3. To install a bundle : ( -s means start bundle immediately after installation is successful)
    install -s mvn:commons-net/commons-net/3.3

4. restart your project bundle.

5. Then restart the karaf server.
```